# Поворот обьекта в сторону его движения

Tags: javascript, three.js

не могу осилить задачку с поворотом обьекта в сторону его движения.

Например, я нажимаю на "W" обьект должен двигаться по оси x и при этом повернуться ко мне попой, а мордочкой в сторону движения http://joxi.ru/p27REzgTo1BWWm

А если, нажал на "S", то развенуться на 180 градусов и уже на меня смотреть мордочкой.

```
if (keyBoard[87]) {
    camera.position.x -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.x -= Math.PI / 10;
}

if (keyBoard[83]) {
    camera.position.x += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.x += Math.PI / 10;
}

if (keyBoard[65]) {
    camera.position.z += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.z += Math.PI / 10;
}

if (keyBoard[68]) {
    camera.position.z -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.z -= Math.PI / 10;
}
```

вот таким макаром организовал движение без поворотов в нужную сторону.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, решил это таким вот образом, но не уверен, что правильно:

```
if (keyBoard[87]) {
    camera.position.x -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.x -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.rotation.y = (Math.cos(bulba.position.y) * Math.PI / 2) * -1;
}

if (keyBoard[83]) {
    camera.position.x += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.x += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.rotation.y = Math.cos(bulba.position.y) * Math.PI / 2;
}

if (keyBoard[65]) {
    camera.position.z += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.z += Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.rotation.y = Math.sin(bulba.position.y);
}

if (keyBoard[68]) {
    camera.position.z -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.position.z -= Math.PI / 10;
    bulba.rotation.y = Math.cos(bulba.position.y) * Math.PI;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите ответ на свой вопрос в англоязычном сегменте: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030508/4045502